# Signing in with "Remember me" option implemented with Spring and Kotlin

Tags: authentication, kotlin, spring, jwt

I'm trying to implement authentication with "Remember me" option using Spring and Kotlin. I would really appriciate if someone could help me find potential issues with that implementation as well as improvements to the code.

Let's start with sign in API. It accepts 3 parameters, `email: String`, `password: String` and `stayLoggedIn: Boolean`.

```java
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/api/auth")
    internal class AuthApi(private val signInService: SignInService) {
        @PostMapping("/sign-in")
        fun signIn(@RequestBody request: SignInRequest, response: HttpServletResponse): ResponseEntity<Void> {
            val tokens = signInService.signIn(request)
            response.addCookie(tokens.accessToken.cookie)
            response.addCookie(tokens.refreshToken.cookie)
            return ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK)
        }
    }
```

As you can see, I'm not returning any response, instead tokens are stored in HttpOnly cookies, so frontend can't access them directly (XSS protection). Now, the service itself is a bit more complex. It performs standard validation of `email` and `password` and then based on `stayLoggedIn` flag, it may save or override generated `refresh_token` and `userId` in database.

```java
@Service
class SignInService(
    private val userRepository: UserRepository,
    private val tokenRepository: RefreshTokenRepository,
    private val tokenUtils: JwtTokenUtils,
    private val passwordEncoder: PasswordEncoder
) {

    fun signIn(request: SignInRequest): AccessTokenDto {
        return userRepository.findByEmail(request.email)
            ?.let { user -> authenticate(request, user) }
            ?: throw EmailNotFound(request.email)
    }


    private fun authenticate(request: SignInRequest, user: User): AccessTokenDto {
        when (validPassword(request.password, user.password)) {
            true -> {
                val refreshToken = tokenUtils.generateRefreshToken(user.id)
                val response = AccessTokenDto(
                    TokenCookie.accessTokenCookie(tokenUtils.generateAccessToken(user.id)),
                    TokenCookie.refreshTokenCookie(refreshToken)
                )
                if (request.stayLoggedIn) saveUserRefreshToken(user, refreshToken)
                return response
            }
            false -> throw IncorrectPassword()
        }
    }

    private fun saveUserRefreshToken(user: User, refreshToken: String) {
        tokenRepository.findByUserId(user.id)?.let {
            tokenRepository.save(it.copy(token = refreshToken))
        } ?: run {
            tokenRepository.save(RefreshToken(userId = user.id, token = refreshToken))
        }
    }

    private fun validPassword(providedPassword: String, actualPassword: String) =
        passwordEncoder.matches(providedPassword, actualPassword)
}
```

Code for `TokenCookie` looks like that

```java
enum class TokenType(val value: String) {
    ACCESS_TOKEN("access_token"), REFRESH_TOKEN("refresh_token")
}

class TokenCookie(name: String, token: String) {
    val cookie: Cookie = Cookie(name, token)

    init {
        this.cookie.isHttpOnly = true
        this.cookie.path = "/"
    }

    companion object {
        fun accessTokenCookie(token: String) = TokenCookie(ACCESS_TOKEN.value, token)
        fun refreshTokenCookie(token: String) = TokenCookie(REFRESH_TOKEN.value, token)
    }
}
```

Let's move on to verification that is performed for each request that is not authentication request `!request.requestURI.startsWith("/api/auth")`

First of all, validation function that produces 3 possible outcomes.
`SUCCESS` if everything is fine, `EXPIRED` if token is valid but has expired and `INVALID` for each other scenario

```java
fun validateToken(authToken: String?, tokenType: TokenType = ACCESS_TOKEN): TokenValidationResult {
    return try {
        val claims = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(tokenSecret).parseClaimsJws(authToken)
        if (claims.body["type"] == tokenType.value) SUCCESS else INVALID
    } catch (ex: UnsupportedJwtException) {
        INVALID
    } catch (ex: MalformedJwtException) {
        INVALID
    } catch (ex: IllegalArgumentException) {
        INVALID
    } catch (ex: SignatureException) {
        INVALID
    } catch (ex: ExpiredJwtException) {
        EXPIRED
    }
}
```

Now, the heart of whole security implementation, `JwtTokenFilter`.

1. First of all, it tries to find `access_token` in request cookies
2. Then it performs validation of that token.

- In case of success, it tries to extend this token duration, which happens only if this request contained valid `refresh_token` as well. Main goal for this is to avoid situation when user logged in without selecting "Remember me" option and he uses my application for over 15 minutes (which is `access_token` expiration time). Without extending this token, after this period of time user will need to provide credentials again.
- In case of expired `access_token`, job is delegated to `ExpiredTokenHandler` that I'll show a bit later. Long story short, it tries to find `refresh_token` stored in database (which happens only if user selected option "Remember me"). If that token is there and it matches token provided with HTTP request, than both tokens are extended.
- In case of invalid `access_token`, I'm not doing anything, which means I'm not storing any `Authentication` in `SecurityContext`, therefore next Spring `Filter` will block access to the system.

```java
@Component
internal class JwtTokenFilter(
    private val tokenUtils: JwtTokenUtils,
    private val expiredTokenHandler: ExpiredTokenHandler
) : OncePerRequestFilter() {
    override fun doFilterInternal(
        request: HttpServletRequest,
        response: HttpServletResponse,
        filterChain: FilterChain
    ) {
        if (!request.requestURI.startsWith("/api/auth")) {
            validateTokens(request, response)
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response)
    }
 
    private fun validateTokens(
        request: HttpServletRequest,
        response: HttpServletResponse
    ) {
        getTokenFromCookies(request, ACCESS_TOKEN)?.let {
            val tokenValidationResult = tokenUtils.validateToken(it.value)
            val userId = tokenUtils.getId(it.value)
            if (tokenValidationResult == SUCCESS) {
                updateSecurityContext(userId)
                extendAccessToken(request, response, userId)
            } else if (tokenValidationResult == EXPIRED) {
                val refreshToken = getTokenFromCookies(request, REFRESH_TOKEN)?.value
                if (expiredTokenHandler.checkRefreshEligibility(response, it.value, refreshToken)) {
                    updateSecurityContext(userId)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun updateSecurityContext(userId: Int) {
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().authentication =
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userId, null, Collections.emptyList())
    }

    private fun getTokenFromCookies(request: HttpServletRequest, tokenType: TokenType) =
        request.cookies?.find { cookie -> cookie.name == tokenType.value }

    private fun extendAccessToken(request: HttpServletRequest, response: HttpServletResponse, userId: Int) {
        getTokenFromCookies(request, REFRESH_TOKEN)?.let {
            if (tokenUtils.validateToken(it.value, REFRESH_TOKEN) == SUCCESS) {
                response.addCookie(TokenCookie.accessTokenCookie(tokenUtils.generateAccessToken(userId)).cookie)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And last but not least, the `ExpiredTokenHandler` that was described above

```java
@Service
class ExpiredTokenHandler(private val tokenRepository: RefreshTokenRepository, private val tokenUtils: JwtTokenUtils) {

    fun checkRefreshEligibility(response: HttpServletResponse, expiredToken: String, refreshToken: String?): Boolean {
        val userId = tokenUtils.getId(expiredToken)
        val savedRefreshToken = tokenRepository.findByUserId(userId)
        return if (validateRefreshToken(refreshToken, savedRefreshToken)) {
            val (newAccessToken, newRefreshToken) = generateNewTokens(userId, savedRefreshToken!!)
            updateCookies(newAccessToken, newRefreshToken, response)
            true
        } else {
            false
        }
    }

    private fun validateRefreshToken(
        refreshToken: String?,
        savedRefreshToken: RefreshToken?
    ): Boolean {
        return refreshToken != null &&
                savedRefreshToken != null &&
                refreshToken == savedRefreshToken.token &&
                tokenUtils.validateToken(refreshToken, REFRESH_TOKEN) == SUCCESS
    }

    private fun updateCookies(accessToken: String, refreshToken: String, response: HttpServletResponse): Boolean {
        response.addCookie(accessTokenCookie(accessToken).cookie)
        response.addCookie(refreshTokenCookie(refreshToken).cookie)
        return true
    }

    private fun generateNewTokens(userId: Int, savedRefreshToken: RefreshToken): Pair<String, String> {
        val newAccessToken = tokenUtils.generateAccessToken(userId)
        val newRefreshToken = tokenUtils.generateRefreshToken(userId)
        tokenRepository.save(savedRefreshToken.copy(token = newRefreshToken))
        return Pair(newAccessToken, newRefreshToken)
    }
}
```

That's the core implementation, if you think that I missed something important then please let me know. I'm looking forward to hear what may be wrong with that approach. What's more, I'm still Kotlin newbie, so perhaps I could utilize this language a bit more.

Comment: Can you confirm that the code is complete and that it functions correctly? If so, I recommend that you [edit] to add a summary of the testing (ideally as reproducible unit-test code).  If it's not working, it isn't ready for review (see [help/on-topic]) and the question may be deleted.